# How to add an EventListener to the Amazon submit button

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to the submit Button from Amazon to be my event so I can read what the person was searching, but I cannot get it to work. I am not sure how to exactly pinpoint the button.

*myscript.js*

```
function getProduct(){
    console.log('getProduct');
    var textbox = document.getElementById('twotabsearchtextbox').value;
    console.log(textbox.value);
    init(); 
}

function init(){
    console.log('in init');
    var i = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-input');
    console.log(i[0].value);
    console.log(i[1].value);
    i[0].addEventListener('onclick', getProduct );
}
function testen(){
    console.log('test');
}
window.onload = init;
```

*manifest.json*

```
{
    "name": "Bachelortest",
    "description": "teste",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version":2,

    "browser_action":{
    "default_icon":"icon.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "permissions":["tabs", "storage", "activeTab" ,"geolocation"],

    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

      "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*","http://*/*", "https://www.amazon.de/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.12.3.min.js","myscript.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

Comment: Please do not write extensions that load content scripts into *every* page, `"matches": ["https://*/*","http://*/*",...` when you are only interacting with very few websites. Doing so makes your extension consume resources for each and every single webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add event listener to the form submit instead:

```
document.querySelector('.nav-searchbar').addEventListener('submit', event => {
  console.log(document.querySelector('#twotabsearchtextbox').value)
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: by the way `i[0].addEventListener('onclick', getProduct )` wasn't working because event is `click`, not `onclick`